# USB Camera not detected under video devices (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, drivers, video, camera

I have a problem concerning the Bresser Mikrocam SP 3.1.

I would like to read out this USB camera in real-time using OpenCV.

There is a camera software delivered with the USB camera, but according to the producing company, the camera should work with any software, but Cheese for example didn't recognize the camera.

The reason for this might be that the camera is not listed under video devices, neither using MacOS, Windows 10 or Ubuntu.

However, it is detected under USB devices, I checked for the camera ID to maybe find missing drivers, but a search on the internet wasn't successful.

Has anybody encountered this specific or a similar problem before and knows how to solve this, or knows a workaround? Would it work to use the USB camera as an IP camera and read out the data using an URL?

Comment: Is it UVC compatible? I'd try first with GTK UVC Viewer. If it's not UVC compatible it may be proprietary in some way or older?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I will check that. The main problem is that it does not appear under video devices, if it would I'd be able to read it out directly using OpenCV, without any additional software.

Comment: So apparently, the camera is not UVC compatible. The camera ID is 0547:1186. Anyone knows how to run it?

Comment: My understanding, which may be limited, is that UVC is a universal standard. Any cameras that aren't UVC will require a proprietary driver, and so the manufacturer must provide the driver for each platform. In my experience manufacturers only provide Windows drivers.